# How can I use rounded values in calculations in Java

Tags: java

Does anybody know how to use rounded values in subsequent calculations?

For example, I'm developing a program that needs a double input for distance but must round down to an integer for unit output. This is to determine the quantity of units in a specific space. I then want to use the units quantity in subsequent calculations.

Problem is when I use the `Math.floor` or `Math.round` methods, the subsequent calculation maintains precision so I'm using, for example 73.43666 rather than 73.

Any suggestions are very welcome!!

Comment: did you googled that question before posting? Math.floor/Math.round???

Comment: Show us some code, and help will happen faster!

Comment: The [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class is your friend!

Comment: You need to know how you want to round: to the nearest integer, towards 0 etc. Based on that you can choose the rounding function. Should 73.6 become 73 or 74?

Comment: " the subsequent calculation maintains precision " show your code please. You're probably using `Math.round(myValue);` when you should be using `myValue = Math.round(myValue);`

Comment: I always need to round down to ensure there is adequate physical space....so I thought Math.floor would do the trick.....and it does superficially but the subsequent calcs use the precise result rather than the rounded result.....I'll add code screenshot below

Comment: Erwin, I just tried writing my variable as a math rounded variable as you suggested above and this is now operating correctly.  You are right, I was just trying to round the double value directly.  Much appreciated.

Comment: numH = ((dimH-vialDia[vialSize])/(0.866*vialDia[vialSize]))+1;
numD = (dimD-((vialDia[vialSize]))/2)/(vialDia[vialSize]);
numH = Math.floor(numH);
numD = Math.floor(numD);
System.out.println("Number of vials in the honeycomb direction = " + (numH));
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Number of vials in the diameter direction = " +  (numD));
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Total number of vials: " +  (numH*numD));
System.out.println()

Answer (score 0):

you can call `intValue()` on the double value to convert it to an integer which obviously will round it

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
int a = (int) Math.round(doubleVar);
```